# Sum all kind of number resulting from regular expression

Tags: javascript, regex, math

I'm working on a function which sum's all numbers from a text:

```js
'use strict';

var sum = function(text, regex) {
  var match;
  return !!(match = text.match(regex || /\d+/g)) ?
    match.reduce(function(prev, curr) {
      return +prev + +curr;
    })
  : 0;
}

console.log(sum('1 12 40'));
console.log(sum('10 12 40'));
console.log(sum('1 12 510'));
console.log(sum('LLLLLLLL'));
console.log(sum('10 1'));
```

And is not working it numbers with points:

```js
    'use strict';

    var sum = function(text, regex) {
      var match;
      return !!(match = text.match(regex || /\d+/g)) ?
        match.reduce(function(prev, curr) {
          return +prev + +curr;
        })
      : 0;
    }

    console.log(sum('1.10 12.40 40.30'));
```

So, i would like to ask for help. How could i also sum numbers with pointers?

Thanks.

Comment: Did you try replacing `\d+` with `/[\d\.]+/g`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a regex which matches numbers with decimal point too

```js
var sum = function(text, regex) {
  return (text.match(regex || /\d*(?:\.\d*)?/g) || [])
  .reduce(function(prev, curr) {
    return prev + +curr;
  }, 0);
}
document.write(sum('1.10 12.40 40.30'));
```

Comment: or `/-?\d*(?:\.\d*)?/g` if you also want to match negative numbers

Comment: This may not matter to many people, but if you're parsing these out of strings that can contain non-numbers as well, then you're going to want to change the `reduce` return to `return (+prev || 0) + (+curr || 0)` to avoid ending up with `NaN` since this regex matches single `"-"` and `"."` as well.

Answer (score 0):

If `sum` is expecting number as string to be parameter, could use `String.prototype.split()` with `RegExp` `/\s/` , `Array.prototype.map()` with `Number` as callback

```js
"use strict";

var sum = function(text, regex) {
  var match;
  return !!(match = text.split(regex || /\s/).map(Number)) ?
    match.reduce(function(prev, curr) {
      return prev + curr;
    })
  : 0;
}

console.log(sum("1.10 12.40 40.30"));
```

Comment: Could alternatively use `RegExp` `[^\d+.]` to match characters that are not digit or `.` character at `.split()`

Answer (score 0):

Given the format of input string, you could first use String split() to split the values, then loop to sum up the values:

```js
function sum(text) {
  var arr = text.split(" ");
  var total = 0;
  for (var i in arr) {
    if (/[\d.]+/g.test(arr[i])) {
      total += parseFloat(/[\d.]+/g.exec(arr[i]));
    }
  }
  document.write("The sum is " + total);
}
sum("1.10 12.40 40.30");
```